# jquery array stored check box not responding

Tags: jquery

[image]I have 4 group of checkboxes, in which i am grouping all this 4 in to an array, after i stored the group checkboxes, i can't add the event to those boxes, i think i am doing something wrong.. any one correct my code?

what i want is when a user click on a checkbox, then can check further withing group(max 4 allowed), if they switch to other group, then rest of the groups need to uncheck, and they have the rights to check 4 from which group they selected.

i am grouping like this, and next i need to disable and unable to group to allowing 4 selection, any good idea to get this done?

```
var geoGroup = [];

$('input:checkbox','#geography').each(function(i){
    if(typeof geoGroup[$(this).attr('name')] == 'undefined')
        geoGroup[$(this).attr('name')] = [];
    geoGroup[$(this).attr('name')].push($(this));

    $('input:checkbox',geoGroup[$(this).attr('name')]).live('click', function(){
        alert('hi')
    })
})
```

Comment: could you provide the associated html please ?

Comment: screen attached for reference, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery 1.7 use `on()` rather than live as `live()` is deprecated. Following uses no array, it simply unchecks other groups.

Assumes that each group is wrapped in a container with a class='checkgroup'

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/dqQwB/1/

```
$('#geography').on('change', 'input:checkbox', function() {
    $('.checkgroup').not($(this).closest('.checkgroup')).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: it works. but always i need a check group can eligible to add any other group. ok let me try that. thanks.

Comment: if you would have provided the html it would have been far easier to create demo and understand issue. The limit of 4 was not easy to understand and still not sure what rules are exactly. It is easy to count how many are checked with jQuery `:checked` selector

Comment: this version limits to only 4  in a group and disables others in group  http://jsfiddle.net/dqQwB/2/

Comment: yes, this is what i looking for. thanks. yes, good idea to place html, let do this in my upcoming request. very thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

With minor cleanup, it runs just fine. There's a minor bug in your original code (repeated in my example) in that you traverse using the context of the array item, when the array item has no children and thus doesn't need to be traversed: http://jsfiddle.net/imsky/j87Sx/1/

```
var geoGroup = [];
$("input:checkbox", "#geography").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    if (name != null) {
        geoGroup[name] = $(this);
        geoGroup[name].click(function() {
            alert("hello");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an array to achieve what you want.

```
        $('input:checkbox', "#geography").each(function(i){
            $(this).click(function(){ 
                var name = $(this).attr('name');
                $('input:checkbox', "#geography").each(function(i){
                    if($(this).attr('name') != name){
                        $(this).attr("checked", false);
                    }
                });
            })
        });
```